# How can I remove this outline? [Bootstrap]

Tags: border, outline

today I want to fix this "outline" or "border" I don't know to describe, but I have a image.
[This outline or border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mere8.png)

Yep, I tried with css but nothing.
Note: It's from navbar (nav), but I want to fix for all selects.

Answer (score 0):

Add this:

```
text-decoration: none;
```

to your css class, and it will work.

Comment: *:focus, *:active {
    text-decoration: none;
} //Nothing happens.

Comment: Dude, this thing is only for texts, i need for selected buttons.